# sql: join and count

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three tabels in my MySQL database.

```
table department (int id, int departent_id);
table position (int id, int department_id)
table test (int id, int position_id)
```

Deparment have mutiple positions, test have multiple department. 
I need to count quantity of tests of each department.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
SELECT count(*), d.department_id FROM department d 
INNER JOIN position p ON p.department_id = d.department_id
INNER JOIN test t ON t.position_id = p.id
GROUP BY d.department_id
```

The group statement groups the counts by department_id

Comment: Thank you! But remove please brackets -- we do not need them here.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*), department.id 
FROM test 
INNER JOIN department 
ON department.id = test.department_id 
GROUP BY department.id;
```

Something like this?

are the positions relevant in the question you ask?